# Lotus/Domino User creation flag fREGExtMailReplicasUsingAdminp: How to specify replication details

Tags: lotus-domino

I need to program a client to Domino Server using Notes C API which registers a new Lotus Notes user. Using REGNewUser (see http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/8.5.3/api853ref.nsf/ef2467c10609eaa8852561cc0067a76f/0326bfa2438ebe9985256678006a6ff2?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,REGNew*) and it looks promising except for the fact that I need to make the user's mail file replicate from the specified mail server to the mail server's cluster partner. There is the flag

```
fREGExtMailReplicasUsingAdminp
```

and the documentation is very brief about it:

"Create mail replicas via the administration process"

If I google the flag I get 4 (!) hits.
How do I specify where the mail file replica is created? Does anyone have any more information about what this flag is actually doing?

Thanks
Kai

Comment: I do not think you can do it in one go. My guess would be the flag means it will use adminp to create the mail file as opposed to creating it directly. Try? Also what about REGNewPerson? Not that I reading quickly I see any functional difference :-)

Comment: Are you mixing up the flag above with fREGCreateMailFileNow / fREGCreateMailFileUsingAdminp? This is not about creation of mail file but create its replica.

Comment: You're right I was thinking about these. In any case it is not evident, unless you try it. But I also do not see any place you can define another server for (another) replica. The only thing I could imagine it might create a local mail file and a server replica(?) So that it uses adminp to create a stub on the server. Just a guess... again :-) In any case I seriously doubt you can create cluster replica in one go. From client you can, but that might not be as simple as one API call.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 weeks of research in the Notes C API reference I found:
In REGNewPerson there are 2 structures REG_MAIL_INFO_EXT and REG_PERSON_INFO and if you set the above mentioned flag in REG_PERSON_INFO then you have to provide a list of replica servers in REG_MAIL_INFO_EXT like this:

```
REG_MAIL_INFO_EXT   mail_info, *pmail_info;
REG_PERSON_INFO     person_info, *pperson_info;
...
pmail_info = &mail_info;
pperson_info = &person_info;
...
// pmail_info->pMailForwardAddress = NULL; // brauchen wir nicht.
pmail_info->pMailServerName = mailserver;
pmail_info->pMailTemplateName = mailfiletemplate;
// do the list crap for replica servers
if (error = ListAllocate (0, 0, FALSE, &hReplicaServers, &pList, &list_size)) {
    goto __error;
}
OSUnlock (hReplicaServers);
pList = NULL;

if (error = ListAddEntry (hReplicaServers, // handle to list
                          FALSE,           // do not include data type
                          &list_size,      // pass list size in memory
                          0,               // index to add
                          replicationserver,  // value to add
                          (WORD) strlen(replicationserver))) // size of value to add
{
    goto __error;
}
// now we can add the handle to the structure
pmail_info->hReplicaServers = hReplicaServers;
...
pperson_info->MailInfo = pmail_info;
...

pperson_info->Flags = fREGCreateIDFileNow | fREGCreateAddrBookEntry | fREGCreateMailFileUsingAdminp;
pperson_info->FlagsExt = fREGExtEnforceUniqueShortName | fREGExtMailReplicasUsingAdminp;
```

In my case this did the trick.